# How to make if statement in beforeEach only work on loadup once?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I set up my router beforeEach, is it possible, for the slug thing to only take action on first load up of page?
For example, if I enter my page it should redirect me from default to phase-first, it works fine. But after when I try to click again on `default` button to redirect me to default page, it keeps redirecting me to `phase-first`. I've tried adding another to path default afterwards but it wont work.

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  let slug = store.state.profile.currentPhase.slug;
  if (to.path === '/phase/default' && slug === 'phase-first') {
    return next('/phase-first');
  }
  if (to.path === '/phase/default') {
    return next('/phase/default');
  }
  next();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```js
let redirectToFirstPhase = true;

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

  // let slug = store.state.profile.currentPhase.slug;
  if (to.path === '/phase/default' && redirectToFirstPhase) {
    redirectToFirstPhase = false;
    next('/phase-first');
  } else {
      next();
  }
})
```